# Display the Name and Value associated with my model in my view

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In my Patrol model I have

```
public string Visibility { get; set; }
```

And in my view if can display the value of Visibility:

```
@Model.Visibility
```

How can I display the word "Visibility" so I could display something like

```
<Visibility>Clear</Visibility>
```

Comment: Is your actual question _"How do I output XML from an MVC controller"_?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your razor view, you should have something like this to get the format your wanted -

```
@String.Format("<{0}>{1}</{2}>", Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.Visibility), @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Visibility), @Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.Visibility));
```

will print -

```
<Visibility>Clear</Visibility>
```

This way you can output the data in any formatted string.

**UPDATE:** As per @CodeCastor point, if you want to output XML to the browser, you can use following code in the controller action -

```
        MyModel model= new MyModel();
        model = new MyModel() { Visibility = "Clear" };

        XmlSerializer xsSubmit = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyModel));
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        XmlWriter xw = XmlWriter.Create(sw);
        xsSubmit.Serialize(xw, model);
        var xml = sw.ToString(); 
        return Content(xml, "application/xml");
```

Comment: I guess you need to additionally wrap it with `Html.Raw`.

Comment: @Torino, I tested my code and it displayed the output exactly in the same way without the usage of Html.Raw

Comment: Thanks, the second was the option, I just couldn't find a great version of your work anywhere on the net so I was just going to nut it out myself. well done!